# Can't get grub2 boot menu via COM2 port

Tags: centos7, grub, serial

I want to connect my "CentOS Linux release 7.6.1810 (Core)"  device via COM2 port,then I modify '/etc/default/grub':

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="serial"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200n8"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="115200n8 serial --speed=115200 --unit=0 --word=8 --parity=no --stop=1"
```

then run:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

as the result I could only get the output after "boot menu", not including the grub2.

PS: I'm using COM2(ttyS1) not COM1(ttyS0)

Answer (score 4):

Your `GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND` is specifying to use serial port 0, but you specifically said you wanted to use serial port 1.

You specified `--unit=0`, which means serial port 0.

You should instead use `--unit=1`, to use serial port 1.

---

Also, your serial command begins with `115200n8` which is not valid and should not be present. It should instead start with `serial`.

Comment: I truly appreciate your timely help.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the second one, simply change the `--unit=0` into `--unit=1`.

> The serial unit 0 is usually called ‘COM1’, so, if you want to use COM2, you must specify ‘--unit=1’ instead. -- [grub manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Serial-terminal.html)

Comment: I'm too young too simple,,,it works!!